# How Do I set a CSP Nonce Using webpack?

Tags: webpack, content-security-policy, nonce

I need to add a nonce to the inline scripts created by webpack and I can't find any documentation on how to configure this. I've found this pr: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/3210/files but I can't figure out how to set `__webpack_nonce__` in my dev environment.

Comment: It's over 4 years later and despite the docs improving and my spending many hours on the issue, I've never gotten this working.